# Does Cable (from Marvel Comics) have children?

Tags: marvel

Does Cable have a son or daughter? And if yes then who is he or she?

Comment: Why do you ask? Is there any evidence that Cable would have kids?

Comment: In the 90s X-men cartoon, Cable had a son named Tyler.

Answer (score 6):

**No confirmed biological children**

He did however adopt and is the guardian of the Omega level mutant Hope Summers (birthname Spalding), the first mutant born after events in ***The House of M***.

Cyclops gives the girl to Cable, as he thinks she will be safer with him. Cable takes her into the future, following numerous jumps into the future to avoid Bishop who wants to kill the girl. Cable’s wife Hope is killed, and Cable names baby Hope after his dead wife.

Comment: So... yes. At least, according to adoptive parents, and adopted kids all over.

Comment: @phantom42 good point fixed

Answer (score 4):

[Cable (Nathan Summers)](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Nathan_Summers_(Earth-616)) is presumed to be the father of [Genesis (Tyler Dayspring)](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Tyler_Dayspring_(Earth-4935)).